# How to know which file is opening in Computer using C#

Tags: c#, windows, operating-system, systems-programming

I want to know the file name which we are opening.
For example:

If we are opening notepad.exe then my program should display that notepad.exe got opened.

If we are opening song.mp3 then my program should display that song.mp3 got open.

If we are opening movie.mpeg then my program must tell that movie.mpeg got open.

If we are opening abc.txt then my program must tell that abc.txt got open.

Here I want to know what files are getting open on my computer.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to list out all files opened. Take a look at the [Listing Used Files](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/OpenedFileFinder.aspx?fid=422864&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26&select=2277170) solution on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com). It lists all the files which are currently open.

Comment: Hi, this solution of CodeProject is only showing the programs running but it is not displaying which file i m opening in media player. It is showing wmplayer.exe running but its not showing that movie.mpeg file got openned in media player.

Comment: this might do the trick..

http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/browse_thread/thread/228ecaeec5b17957/93759f6c1a02c971?lnk=raot&pli=1

Comment: Please look at the method `EnumerateOpenedFiles` in the codeproject link i provided, this lists out all files which are open...
the application (which is available for download) is capable of listing open files from specific folders as well).